# unable to call anchor tag in html?

Tags: html

The Search Button below does not take the control to the div tag with id resultLogBus when clicked ?

```
<a href="#resultLogBus" class="ui-btn" onclick="getBusTime();" >Search </a>

<fieldset class="ui-field-contain" data-role="controlgroup">

   <a href="#myPopupDialog2" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="none" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" onclick="getUserPost();" >View Post</a>

   <div id="resultLogBus" >
      <h5>Bus time will be displayed here real time once you select the above filters and click search </h5>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<a name="resultLogBus"></a>` before the element.  So your code will look like

```
<a name="resultLogBus"></a>
<div id="resultLogBus" >
    <h5>Bus time will be displayed here real time once you select the above filters and click search </h5>
</div>
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/98Fkr/1/)